# What are the parameters of \newpagestyle?

Tags: pagestyle

I see `\newpagestyle` used with `\sethead` and `\setfoot`, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79731/how-to-apply-a-custom-pagestyle-with-titlesec-package-to-a-part-of-a-document),  but I cannot find any information on what those arguments for `\sethead` and `\setfoot` mean.

Comment: That page doesn't explain `\sethead` and `\setfoot`

Comment: They seem to be `titleps` commands. See page 2 of its documentation (titleps.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example page (odd page 3) which should explain the six parameters:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead[A][B][C]% even
    {D}{E}{F}%       odd
  \setfoot[a][b][c]% even
   {d}{e}{f}%        odd
}
\pagestyle{main}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]